# Is there a way to recover deleted records from a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I have deleted by mistake thousands of records in a PostgreSQL Table, and i desperately want my data back.
I wonder if there is any mean i can get my records back.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Restore from your backup

Comment: If you are incredibly lucky you won't have commuted your delete transaction and can issue a ROLLBACk. Otherwise you should be looking fot the backups.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the reply,  we have only a backup of the hosting server.

Comment: @mhawke unfortunately the transactions are committed

Comment: While in theory there are things you might be able to do if you stopped your PostgreSQL installation immediately after this, you aren't going to be in a position to do them otherwise you wouldn't be asking on stackoverflow. You have just learnt why it is important to have a backup policy I'm afraid.